# What is better to say "zoom in" or "zoom in on"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here is a sentence for you to have an example:

> Zoom in the picture when the anchorwoman says "GUESS WHAT?".

The question is, should I use zoom in or zoom in on, is there any difference between these two phrases or they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: I feel that the "on" is superfluous, and less formal/more casual.  It creates a little pause, and redirects a bit of momentum to the idea to come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would normally say:

- Zoom **in on** the picture

or possibly:

- zoom **into** the picture

"Zoom in the picture" is not idiomatic - 'in the picture' refers to the things seen in the image.